# How to determine the cash flows of a Mortgage backed security?

Tags: fixed-income, mbs

Suppose there is a **$400 million** mortgage pass-through security with a **7.5%** pass-through rate, a weighted average coupon of **8.125%** and a weighted average maturity of **357 months**, how to compute the cash flows for the next two months assuming a **100** Principal Securities Association(PSA)?

I am quite confused as to whether I have to use the single monthly mortality rate or the conditional prepayment rate to arrive at the solution.
Any leads or solutions would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you would want to know the payment frequency of the MBS to know which prepayment assumption to use. In the U.S., the standard MBS pass-through security has monthly cash flows so in this case you would want to use the SMM, which is a monthly prepayment rate.

SMM, CPR and PSA are all examples of quotation conventions for prepayment rates; SMM is a monthly rate, CPR is an annualized rate, and PSA corresponds to a vector of CPRs (or, equivalently, SMMs).